# The Gauss Map in Algebraic Geometry

Tags: algebraic-geometry

At the moment I am reading Joe Harris' book on algebraic geometry. I am stuck at two points:
1.) The Gauss Map is a regular map
2.) The Gauss Map of a hypersurface is quasi-finite.

Both statements can be found on page 188. I have unsuccesfully tried to prove them. For 2 I also tried some examples, but couldn't see any general pattern.
Any help is very much appreciated. Thanks a lot!!